# How to list "apply from" scripts in gradle

Tags: api, gradle, plugins

In my `build.gradle` file, I apply gradle scripts as following:

```
apply from: new File(rootDir, 'scripts/script1.gradle')
apply from: new File(rootDir, 'scripts/script2.gradle')
```

These files are not listed in the plugin list `project.plugins`.

How can I retreive in a task the scripts files I included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. Perhaps you could use a variable

```
ext {
    scripts = ['scripts/script1.gradle', 'scripts/script2.gradle']
}
scripts.each {
    apply from: new File(rootDir, it)
}
task printScripts {
    doLast {
       println "Scripts = $scripts"
    }
}
```